# Discard unstaged folder

Tags: git

I created a new folder in my project and now I want to discard that unstaged folder. I know how to discard unstaged files by using `git checkout -- .`, however, that command doesn't discard the folder.

Comment: If the folder is empty, git doesn't care. If not, try to discard the files in the directory.

Comment: If it is unstaged, then why not use OS commands/UI to delete the folder (since it is just one folder)?

Comment: @crashmstr I could but i was just wondering how to do it in git

Answer (score 5):

`git clean -df` will remove untracked files and directories, including empty directories.

Comment: So what is the difference between this and git checkout -- .?

Comment: `git checkout` will update the index version of the files to `HEAD`. If you've just created a new folder and never added it to git, this is called an untracked file. It won't be in the index, and you'll get this error: `error: pathspec 'file_name' did not match any file(s) known to git.`. `git clean` is for removing untracked files.

Comment: OP's questions specifies a single folder. I am worried this command will remove other stuff accidentally.